# Deploying Custom SharePoint feature with multiple list with content types

Tags: list, content-type, features

I wanted to ask if anyone has experienced the following, and what has been their solution.

Scenario:

I have created 2x VS solutions with features, the first includes core item for example: Site Columns, Content types, Branding etc

The second is the App solution, with Scripts, Pages and lists/libraries related to the Apps

With the Core, I created separate features for the Site columns, content types etc, and all deploys well.

The second solution is for the App, which has features for the App code, and a single feature for the Lists/Libraries.
"This is where my issue is - And it's odd!"

When I activate the feature for the lists, the lists get created BUT every list inherits the SAME Content Type.

The same content type??

So, my solution to the issue with to create a separate feature for each list/library. Now that seems really counter-productive.

Does anyone have a better solution??

Thank you to all in advance.

regards
Shaun